# Include в функции или методе

Tags: include, классы, php

Есть класс. Есть метод. Хочу внутри метода вызывать инклюд, чтобы область видимости переменных была и вне этого метода.

То есть я хочу вызвать метод, который вызовет инклюд, переменные которого будут видны вне этого метода, как будто этот икнлюд вызвали среди скрипта. Насколько это возможно?

// Я знаю, что такое область видимости переменных. Но, возможно, есть какой-то способ, который позволяет "оглобализовать" подключение инклюда. Надеюсь, я выразился довольно ясно. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказки.

---

Наглядный пример, как бы я хотел:

*Файл include.php*

```
$array = array(
 1 => "one",
 2 => "two"
)
```

*Файл index.php*

```
class test
{
 public function load()
 {
  include('./include.php');
 }
}

$test = new test();

$test->load();

var_dump($array);
```

*Вывод*

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
}
```

Ясное дело, что так работать не будет. Но, возможно, есть какие-то обходные пути или способы сделать примерно так?

Comment: 1. Возвращайте в файле контекст простым `return array();`
2. В методе глобализуйте через паттерн [Registry](http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php).

Comment: @Etki, суть в том, что я хочу использовать переменные из основного файла в подключаемом и наоборот. Метод я хочу использовать для упрощения подключения большинства скриптов. А ретерны я и так активно использую.

Comment: @vtvz, ну и чем тогда Registry не подходит?

---

Вообще если у вас в файле одновременно и объявляются переменные, и выполняется логика, то это очень нехорошо с т.з. архитектуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда возникают такие вопросы, надо просто написать отдельный скрипт и провести эксперимент.  А инклюд, насколько понимаю, просто включает кусок кода. Что так впишешь, что заинклюдишь. Я не пробовал, но скорее всего инклюженые переменные будут инкапсулированы как обычные.

```
Файл include.php

$array = array(
 1 => "one",
 2 => "two"
)
//1 вариант 
$_SESSION['array']=$array;

//2 вариант
$GLOBALS['array']=$array;
```

Comment: @Димка, будут, но внутри области видимости метода, а автору как раз и надо прокинуть их наружу.

Comment: Я вроде как проверил все и нагуглил, прежде чем писать сюда вопрос.

Comment: Затупил, осознал, подумал, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Димка, в сессию-то зачем? Оно ж а) может не существовать и б) сохранится ведь на диск.

Comment: Просто как вариант. Мы же ищем обходные пути. :))

Answer (score 0):

Файл include.php

```
return array(
 1 => "one",
 2 => "two"
);
```

Файл index.php

```
    class test
    {
     public function load()
     {
      $data = include('./include.php');
      return $data;
     }
    }

$test = new test();

var_dump($test->load());
```

Вывод

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
}
```